# Not able to decide which data control to use for dynamically created rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am fetching data from database. Initially it will return me root element rows, which can have multiple child elements. Problem is I am fetching each parent row and then if I select one row, it will return child rows of that with new rows added for same automatically. I am not able to decide between grid view or datalist. Which will suffice my scenerio or is there better way to do this. 
The data returned from database is huge, so performance wise I need to get appropriate control.

**Below is an example**

Parent elements :

[image]

Child elements of particular rows , in this example of Current Liabilitiess. Each row will have different amounts associated with that. It can go upto any hierarchy level:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you have already sort out that either datalist or gridview. I suggest that DataList as it is more flexible and powerful and you can utilize javascript to hide and display nested row.

GridView is also powerful control but it that case also you have to do nested gridview. Like when row get clicked you have to display another gridview in that item.

There are many third party control available then do same functionality that you need.

Comment: Any other control is always welcome provided that works best. I have to get child elementss only when parent node is clicked , Otherwise performance will be slow if i retrieve all rows at once.

Comment: For third party there is telerik asp.net ajax grid that I have used http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx. If you want to use existing asp.net control then Listview control give you flexibility but you have to handle that dynamic loading part with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Treeview Control. Its more flexible.

Comment: I can't , I don't have to get only nodes, but with nodes there is associated data which is not possible in tree view